# jQuery button click wont run

Tags: jquery, onclick

I cannot get this simple script to run and been staring at it for awhile now and don't see any syntax errors. Simply want the alert to show on click.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type='text/javascript'>

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#authenticate_button").click(function() {
        alert("click");
    });
});

</script>

</head>
<body>
    <input id="code" type="text"> 
    <button id='authenticate_button'>Authenticate</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you opening the file in http:// ? If you open it in file:// it can't work.

Comment: what does the console in the browser say?

Comment: This isn't running in a local file is it?

Comment: It is a local file, why does that not work?

Comment: Tried this in jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/TeuBp/ and i can see the alert.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're opening the file with your web browser directly. `//` is shorthand for your current protocol (which is `file://`), so jQuery isn't loading from Google's CDN.

You need to explicitly specify the protocol by adding `http:` before `//` in this line:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I'd also add a doctype:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try out with this:

**Using jQuery's CDN provided by MediaTemple**

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
```

**Using Microsoft's CDN**

```
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.9.0.js"></script>
```

as an alternative to jQuery js file.

I would suggest to go for this:

```
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.9.0.min.js"></script>  
<script>  
     // Fallback to loading jQuery from a local path if the CDN is unavailable  
     (window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="/scripts/jquery-1.9.0.min.js"><\/script>'));  
</script>
```